# Property 'ripples' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'. in angular component

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm trying to implement a jquery function on angular but terminal is returning the following error:

> Property 'ripples' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

While on my console I'm getting the following error: **ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

Here is my code snippet

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jqueryui';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.image').ripples('show');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `ripples()` isn't a standard jQuery method. You need to include the library which contains it to the page

Comment: I installed npm i jquery.ripples

Comment: You will also need to include it in the page's scripts too.

Comment: @phuzi Yes I did it  "styles": [
              "node_modules/jquery.ripples/dist/jquery.ripples-min.js" ]

Comment: Not sure that `styles` is correct for something that would normally be included as a `<script>`

Comment: try "___scripts___": [ "node_modules/jquery.ripples/dist/jquery.ripples-min.js" ] instead. I'd also be tempted to include jQuery like this too so that jQuery is always loaded first. That or find an Angular version of that plugin if you really need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare **$** as following ,

```
declare var $;
```

instead of

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

**UPDATED** 
Update your `angular.json` file

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              //Here ripple module path
            ],
```

This will solve your error -> *$ not declared* and also of *ripple*.

Comment: did you imported CDN of jquery ?

Comment: yes in my angular.json file :   "styles": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/jquery.ripples/dist/jquery.ripples-min.js" ]

Comment: you need to import .js file in `scripts` array ... not in styles .. correct it and it will work .